# How to solve these linear equations using matrices?

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

I've been asked to find $A^{-1}$ and find the soluion to
$3x-4y+2z=-1; 
x+z=2$ and $2x+3y+5z=7$

where $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
-4 & 3 & 0 \\
2 & 5& 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And $$ A^{-1}= \frac{-1}{9} 
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 3 & -3 \\
4 & 1 & 4 \\
-26 & -11 & 17 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It looks quiet straightforward, but what
s confusing me is to bring it to the form where $x,y,z$ are the columns, I hav e to find the transpose, but this matrix's transpose, obviously has a different inverse, what to do?

Comment: How does $A$ relate to the system?

Comment: sorry, entered a wrong entry

Comment: When you represent a system with a matrix, the rows should represent equations, not columns.

Comment: yes, I understand that, which is why I said I know I shoud ideally find $A^T$ first, but I have to use $A^{-1}$ aloe , to solve this

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & - 4 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z\\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
2 \\
7
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Find $A^{-1}$ and multiply it on the left of both sides. If you think of it this way, you get $x,y,z$ in a column, as you like. In your example you have

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
x & z & y
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1\\
-4 & 3 & 0\\
2 & 5 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &
7 &
2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}

So you'd want to multiply by the inverse on the right.

Comment: yes, thanks, I know that by taking $A^T$ it becomes easy, but I have you use teh inverse of the original matrix $A$ alone

Comment: I'm not allowed to find $(A^{-1})^{T}$

Comment: Oh, thanks for the last part, I was trying to do something like that, but I didn't think of multiplying on the left instead. Thannks a ton!